# Where can I find the default Oomph profiles included in the Eclipse installer?

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I would like to base my custom Eclipse setup on the Oomph profile for Java EE developers included in the standard [Eclipse Installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer) but I can't seem to find it anywhere in the installer directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yout need to check the "Show tool bar contributions" checkbox in the "Setup Tasks" preference page,

[image: Eclipse Oomph preference page]

Then from the toolbar select the "Open user" menu and under the "Parent Models" you will find:

- The `setup` file corresponding to the installed IDE. `org.eclipse.products.setup`
- The `setup` file correspondig to the complete eclipse.org catalog `org.eclipse.setup`

[image: Parent Models in Oomph]